# How to convert the code below to a powershell code

Tags: powershell

how to translate this code, this was taken from The DropBox API Explorer but a don't know how to translate it to a powershell code specifically using Invoke-RestMethod or another way, the thing is that i need list the content of a folder store in dropbox, all this using powershell and security token

```
POST /2/files/list_folder 
Host: https://api.dropboxapi.com User-Agent: api-explorer-client Authorization: Bearer dropbox_token 
Content-Type: application/json  
{     
"path": "/documentos" 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST API's are easy to work with in PowerShell. You just need to pass an ordered hash table containing the headers and a string containing the body. If the body is a `json` string, which appears to be the case, you can create an ordered hash table and pipe it to `ConvertTo-Json` to produce the string.

Use the following:

```
$BaseAPIPath = "https://replaceWithDropboxBaseApi.com/"

$headers = [ordered]@{
    "Host"          = "https://api.dropboxapi.com"
    "User-Agent"    = "api-explorer-client"
    "Authorization" = "Bearer dropbox_token"
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
}

$body = [ordered]@{
    "path" = "/documentos"
} | ConvertTo-Json

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Header $headers -Body $body -Uri "$BaseAPIPath/2/files/list_folder"
```

You will need to replace `$BaseAPIPath` with the path to the dropbox api (as it was not provided in your question).

See [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6)